# Even-odd partitioned groups!

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with the property $G=G_e\dot{\cup} G_o$ with 
$G_oG_o\subseteq G_e\leq G$.

($\dot{\cup}$ denotes disjoint union, $\leq$ is subgroup notation, and $G_o^{-1}=\{x^{-1}: x\in G_o\}$)

We observe that

(1) $G_o^{-1}=G_o$, $G_oG_o=G_e$, $G_oG_e=G_eG_o=G_o$;

(2) $|G:G_e|=2$, $|G|=2|G_o|=2|G_e|$;

(3) $(\mathbb{Z},+)$, $S_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2m}$ enjoy the property.

Now, is there any characterization for such groups?

Comment: You haven't told us what $G_e$ stands for, nor $G_O$, nor $G_o$.

Comment: Also you have used the tag finite-groups, but not said whether you are assuming that $G$ is finite.

Comment: Because we have both finite and infinite classes of such groups (Derek).                                         Why is it not true (Geoff)?

Comment: @M.H.Hooshmand  I think the subject which you mentioned is important, since it is related to graded structure for group rings.Please  see the paragraph after example 2.2 of this note(and its consequences, in particular proposition 2.4):  http://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/2012/729745/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group $G$ has subsets $G_e$ and $G_o$ as mentioned above, iff $G$ has a normal subgroup of index 2. 
If $G_e$ is a normal subgroup of index 2, then $G_e$ and $G_o=xG_e$, $x\notin G_e$, satisfied the condition of the problem.

Now, suppose such subsets $G_e$ and $G_o$ exist. Since $G_e$ is a subgroup, and $G_e\cap G_o=\emptyset$ $G_o^{-1}\subseteq G_o$, and so, $G_o^{-1}=G_o$. Therefore $G_oG_o=G_e$. This implies that $G_ex=xG_e=G_o$ for $x$ not in $G_e$.This leads $G_e$ to be a normal subgroup of index 2.